# Concatenate results of `apply` in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I would like to apply a function to each element/row of a pandas Series/DataFrame and concatenate/stack the results into a single DataFrame.
E.g., I may start with a Series `s = pd.Series(["a", "b,c", "d,e,f"])`, and I would like to obtain as a final result `res = pd.Series(["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"])`

A slow way of doing this would be:

```
res = []
for _, x in s.items():
    res.append(pd.Series(s.split(",")))
res = pd.concat(res, ignore_index=True)
```

I would like to explore the internal functionality of pandas. It seems that there should be a way of doing this by starting with something like `s.apply(lambda x: x.split(","))` or `s.str.split()`, which gives a series of lists...

**Remarks:**

- The simple example above could be actually solved using something like `pd.Series(",".join(s.tolist()).split(","))`, but I am looking for a generalizable solution.
- Note that this is not a duplicate of [Apply elementwise, concatenate resulting rows into a DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41191358/6151828) (where *apply* is used in a generic sense rather than as a name of pandas function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in two steps:

- split each string into a list of strings delimiting by comma
- explode the column made up of lists of strings into a series of strings

This can be achieved in a single line that combines the map with the flatmap:

```py
s.str.split(',').explode()
```